# Mealy machine 1011 detector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I write a VHDL program for Mealy machine that can detect the pattern 1011 as the following:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY mealy_detector_1011 IS
    PORT(
        rst_n   : IN STD_LOGIC;
        clk     : IN STD_LOGIC;
        data    : IN STD_LOGIC;
        result  : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE beh OF mealy_detector_1011 IS
    TYPE state IS (IDLE, GOT1, GOT10, GOT101);
    SIGNAL current_state : state;
    SIGNAL next_state   : state;
BEGIN
    REG: PROCESS(clk, rst_n)
    BEGIN
        IF rst_n = '0' THEN
            current_state <= IDLE;
        ELSIF rising_edge(clk) THEN
            current_state <= next_state;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS REG;

    NEXTSTATE: PROCESS(data, current_state)
    BEGIN
        CASE current_state IS
            WHEN IDLE =>
                IF data = '1' THEN
                    next_state <= GOT1;
                ELSE next_state <= IDLE;
                END IF;
            WHEN GOT1 =>
                IF data = '0' THEN
                    next_state <= GOT10;
                ELSE next_state <= GOT1;
                END IF;
            WHEN GOT10 =>
                IF data = '1' THEN
                    next_state <= GOT101;
                ELSE next_state <= IDLE;
                END IF;
            WHEN GOT101 =>
                IF data = '1' THEN
                    next_state <= GOT1;
                ELSE 
                    next_state <= GOT10;
                END IF;
            WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
        END CASE;
    END PROCESS NEXTSTATE;
    result <= '1' WHEN (current_state = GOT101 and data = '1') ELSE '0';
END beh;
```

and file .do to simulating as the following

```
vcom mealy_detector_1011.vhd
vsim mealy_detector_1011
add wave -r /*
force -freeze /clk 1 0, 0 50 -r 100
force -freeze /rst_n 0 0, 1 10
force -freeze /data 0 0, 1 80, 0 180, 1 230, 0 330, 1 470, 0 530, 1 570, 0 620
run 800 ns
```

However, my simulation result isn't correct. Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep getting answers from people who seem to perceive a problem with `result`.

The issue is that `data` is not synchronous to `clk`.  You have transitions all over the place, the mealy output is doing exactly what's it's supposed to do.

It's a combinatorial output and shouldn't be used as a clock.  It can be used as an enable or an input to a register operating on `clk`.

Here's a test bench for those of us without Modelsim:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mealy_1011_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of mealy_1011_tb is
    signal rst_n:     std_logic := '0';
    signal  clk:      std_logic := '1';
    signal  data:     std_logic := '0';
    signal  result:   std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.mealy_detector_1011
    port map (
        rst_n => rst_n,
        clk => clk,
        data => data,
        result => result
    );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 50 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 799 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        rst_n <= '1';
        wait for 70 ns;   
        data <= '1';     --  80 ns
        wait for 100 ns;
        data <= '0';     -- 180 ns
        wait for 50 ns;
        data <= '1';     -- 230 ns
        wait for 100 ns;
        data <= '0';     -- 330 ns
        wait for 140 ns;
        data <= '1';     -- 470 ns
        wait for 60 ns;
        data <= '0';     -- 530 ns
        wait for 40 ns;   
        data <= '1';     -- 570 ns
        wait for 50 ns;
        data <= '0';     -- 620 ns
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And it gives the same answer as your simulation:

[image: mealy_1011_tb.png]
*(clickable)*

You don't want to see the extra dip  on `result`, make `data` clock synchronous. Your statemachine is doing exactly what's it's supposed to.

And if `data` were clock synchronous you could gate `result` with `clk` using `not clk nand result` and produce a result event clock.

Comment: Can you give me your code? My english isn't good. I can't understand clearly your comment. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write your Mealy outputs into the transition if-then-else branch of your process.

```
NEXTSTATE: PROCESS(data, current_state)
BEGIN
    -- default assignments
    next_state <= state;       -- so your code won't create latches
    result     <= '0';         -- result is always 0, except of transition GOT101 to GOT1

    CASE current_state IS
        WHEN IDLE =>
            IF data = '1' THEN
                next_state <= GOT1;
            ELSE next_state <= IDLE;
            END IF;
        WHEN GOT1 =>
            IF data = '0' THEN
                next_state <= GOT10;
            ELSE next_state <= GOT1;
            END IF;
        WHEN GOT10 =>
            IF data = '1' THEN
                next_state <= GOT101;
            ELSE next_state <= IDLE;
            END IF;
        WHEN GOT101 =>
            IF data = '1' THEN
                result     <= '1';
                next_state <= GOT1;
            ELSE 
                next_state <= GOT10;
            END IF;
        WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
    END CASE;
END PROCESS NEXTSTATE;
```

Comment: I'll supply a test bench.  Simulate your process. It'll get the same answer.  The default assignment to `next_state` isn't needed.  To prove it comment out the others case.  Notice `next_state` is assigned every where.  (`state` has full coverage in the case statement and every if and else has an assignment to `next_state`).

Comment: @DavidKoontz Sorry, I missed the `when others` line. Of cause, `next_state <= current_state`is in this particular case not needed, but most people forget to add code lines if they extend their FSMs. So it's a good choice for a coding style to declare default assignment for every output :)